# Sitecore SXA Installation

Tags: sitecore, accelerator, sitecore8.2, sitecore-sxa

Im trying to setup Sitecore SXA (Sitecore Experience Accelerator) in 8.2 sitecore, i have done everything properly as mentioned in Installation document but i am not able to see any options, Toolbox, or partial views, renderings which need to come with Sitecore SXA installation.

Is SXA a licensed module ?, can't we use SXA features with default SXA module which we get from http://dev.sitecore.net [Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/11/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_11_Initial_Release.aspx)

Comment: SXA is a licensed module I'm afraid. You'll need to speak to your Sitecore Sales rep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sitecore Experience Accelerator License Error – Sitecore.SXA Not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036976/sitecore-experience-accelerator-license-error-sitecore-sxa-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Sitecore Experience Accelerator a licensed module and you need to get a new license to setup this module to work in your system . I am not sure if the new license will have addition cost or in the same cost of the old license .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a licensing issue, but did you try to create Tenants and Sites? IT's a common mistake to install everything and just go and preview the Home page. SxA have scripts to set everything up.

Try this:

Go the your content editor tree and right click in **content** and create a **Tenant**.
Right click in your new **Tenant** and create a **Site**.

Open the home of this new site in your Experience Editor. Everything should be there.

More about tenants and sites:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/create_a_tenant_and_a_site