# Sitecore Experience Accelerator License Error – Sitecore.SXA Not Found

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2, sitecore-sxa

Is Sitecore Experience Accelerator(SXA) a licensed module ?

I Followed below official Site and install the SXA.

[Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.0 Initial Release](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/10/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_10_Initial_Release.aspx)

In above SXA official site not mentioned about licence.

We are using Sitecore Experience Platform 8.2.

Before install SXA, I installed package "Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.1 for Sitecore 8" ,after that I installed package "Sitecore Experience Accelerator for 8.2", successfully installed.

I able to create "tenant folder" and "tenant " in that tenant I able to create site, but while seeing the experience (or) preview mode of any item in that site getting error "A required license is missing".

also tried to clear my browser history and cache, then also getting same error.

Please confirm "SXA"  is licence or free? If it is licence how to purchase it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be sure to check out http://sitecore.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SXA is licensed and not free. You should contact your [local sales office](http://www.sitecore.net/en/company/contact-us).

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your Sitecore account manager to get the new Sitecore license file to support SXA feature. In case if you are Sitecore partner, then this may not cost anything but please check with Sitecore.